# Authorizing Application Access to BigQuery without User Interaction, via PHP

Tags: google-api, google-bigquery, google-api-php-client

I have a website, that does the simple work of fetching an USN from Google BigQuery on the cloud. Now, while accessing each time, I need to have a Google Account and also that particular email-id, should have the "permission" assigned in the "Team tab". I basically want the website to be available to everyone. And i am using PHP, so I need help about the functions that will be useful here.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to build an application that is authorized to access the BigQuery API (as opposed to requiring a user authorization step) is to use OAuth2 service accounts. Essentially, a service account authorization provides certificate-based authorization for "server to server" interactions (such as your server side PHP script interacting with the BigQuery API).

There is documentation for using the Google PHP Client library with service account authorization [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2#Service_Accounts).

Comment: I had tried that php script , i got a fatal error saying , 'Google_Auth Exception' with message 'Unable to parse the p12 file. Is this a .p12 file?...

Comment: Can you confirm that you: 1. Downloaded your private key file (*.p12) as described in the instructions 2. It is available to your PHP script? (in other words, is it in the correct path?)

Comment: Yes, have downloaded the private key , and have labelled it as key.p12, and have put in the same directory , and have defined const key="key.p12".

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a 'service account' through google console and download the private key file (.p12) on your server. And use following code

```
/**
   * setup service client using key file
   * @param String $keyFileLoc location of .p12 file provided in google console
   * @param String $clientEmail client location provided in google console
   */
   function setupServiceClient($keyFileLoc,$clientEmail){
       $client = new Google_Client();
       $service = new Google_Service_Bigquery($client);
       $client->setApplicationName("My Application Name");
       $key = file_get_contents($keyFileLoc);
       $cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
           $clientEmail,
           array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery'),
           $key
       ); 
       $this->client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
       return $service;
  }
```